# using swiftlint to enforce a unique coding guideline

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I want to enforce the following coding guideline in a swift project

- All strings should be placed in the Strings file.
- We should NOT be
  hardcoding or storing any strings in the storyboard, xibs or classes.

Is it possible to use swiftlint for the above 2 rules?

Comment: No, it is not possible using swiftlint.

Comment: But you  can creat your own custom rules